# Giving pictures the same projectID while inserting their path's into a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm rather new to HTML/PHP/MySQL and have this question:

My form has 3 input fields from where the user can pick a picture from a filemanager and on insert the path to the picture will be inserted into a table called photoProjects(photoID, photoName). Later on in the project, when there are more pictures in the table, they will be joined it with a Projects table so I can show different projects with their pictures on the website.

My form

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="photoInsert">
<table width="902" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<h2>Insert pictures for a project</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photos:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH1" type="text" id="absurl1" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl1&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photo:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH2" type="text" id="absurl2" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl2&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photo:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH3" type="text" id="absurl3" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl3&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><br>
<input type="image" src="images/checkButton.jpg" title="Insert"/>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="photoInsert" value="photoInsert">
</form>
```

with this INSERT INTO:

```
$uploadPhotos = sprintf( "INSERT INTO photoProjects (photoPath) VALUES (%s),(%s),(%s)",
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH1' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH2' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH3' ], "text" ));
```

The code above works but now I want to extend the form(select a project) and table with a projectID column(photoID, photoPath, projectID) but how do I give the pictures the same projectID while inserting their path's into the table so I can filter them by projectID. Later on in the project, when there are more pictures in the table, they will be joined it with a Projects table so I can show a project with pictures on the website.

I was reading something like this but I can't get it to work...

```
$uploadPhotos = sprintf( "INSERT INTO photoProjects (photoPath, projectID) VALUES (%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s)",
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH1' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH2' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH3' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PROJECT' ], "text" ));
```

My new form

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="photoInsert">
<table width="902" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<h2>Insert pictures for a project</h2><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Project</th>
</tr>

<label class="select">
<select name="PROJECT" class="form-control">
<option value="0" selected disabled>Choose a project</option>
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_Projects['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Projects['nameProject']; ?></option>
<?php } while ($row_Projects = mysql_fetch_assoc($Projects)); ?>
</select> 
</label>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photos:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH1" type="text" id="absurl1" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl1&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photo:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH2" type="text" id="absurl2" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl2&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="108">Photo:</th>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="input-append">
<input name="PHOTOPATH3" type="text" id="absurl3" size="50"/>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=absurl3&relative_url=1">Choose a picture</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><br>
<input type="image" src="images/checkButton.jpg" title="Insert"/>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="photoInsert" value="photoInsert">
</form>
```

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong or have to do?

Comment: try the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe wrong or misunderstand the question, but I think you need to update your Insert Query, to add projectID (`$_POST['PROJECT']`) to each insert value:

```
$uploadPhotos = sprintf( "INSERT INTO photoProjects (photoPath, projectID) VALUES (%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s)",
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH1' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PROJECT' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH2' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PROJECT' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PHOTOPATH3' ], "text" ),
GetSQLValueString( $_POST[ 'PROJECT' ], "text" ));
```

Comment: Hi justbaron, thanx for your answer. It worked. It was so simple that I overlooked it completely...

Comment: @robindevries feel free to accept the answer and up vote, if you wish